# Display TFS Kanban custom columns in backlog grid

Tags: tfs

I customized the Kanban board to include new columns.  These columns are mapped to the existing states, (New, Active, Resolved, Complete).

My backlog shows only the states. Is there a way for the backlog to display the new columns and not the state to which they are mapped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, this is not a feature I have seen. If you really think it will be of value, your best place is the [VS User Voice site](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to add new meta-states?